# Driver vieux/sshfs mount folder in manager node docker swarm

Tags: docker-swarm

I install docker swarm on only one server, that has only one manager node.
I tried to create docker service use sshfs mount volume for folder in this server.
(One server has storage folder for mount volume and manager node).
But when run comment create service. that show error mount connect reset by peer.
There can setup mount sshfs and docker swarm only one server?